# Storing data in a ruby C extension - terrible idea or not?

Tags: ruby, cextension

My team is working on an MMO server in Ruby, and we opted to start moving computationally intensive operations into a C extension. As part of that effort, we moved the actual data storage into C (using Data_Get_Struct and all that). So, for example, each Ruby "Zone" object has an associated "ZoneKernel::Zone" C struct where the actual binary data is stored.

Basically, I'm wondering if this is a terrible idea or not. I'm not super familiar with the ruby internals, but it seems like the data should be fine as long as the parent Zone stays in memory on the ruby side (thus preventing garbage collection of the C data).

One caveat is that we've been getting semi-regular "Stack Consistency Errors" that crash our server - this seems like potentially a related memory issue (instead of just your garden variety segfault) - if anyone has any knowledge of what that might be, I would appreciate that as well!

Comment: This probably should be on programmers.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [the documentation to `Data_Wrap_Struct(klass, mark, free, ptr)` function](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/README.EXT#L555):

> The `free` argument is the function to free the pointer allocation. If
>   this is `-1`, the pointer will be just freed.
>
> These `mark` / `free` functions are invoked during GC execution.

Your wrapped native structure will be automatically freed when its corresponding Ruby object is finalized. Until that happens, your data will not be freed unless you do so manually.

Writing C extensions doesn't *guarantee* a performance boost, but it almost always increases the complexity of your code. Profile your server in order to measure your performance gains, and develop your `Zone` class in pure Ruby if viable.

Answer (score 0):

In general I like to keep any data that could change outside of my source. Loading it from YAML or a database means you can tweak the data to your heart's content without needing to recompile. Obviously, if your compile time and load times are fast then it's not as big an issue, but it's still a good idea to separate the two.

I favor YAML, because it's a standard format, so you could access the same file from any number of languages. You could load it directly into the C side, or into the Ruby side, depending on what seems faster/smarter.